# Xamarin.Forms.Color byte format

Tags: xamarin.forms

In what base are colors in [Xamarin.Forms.Color](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Color/)? Or rather how many bytes it takes to store a pixel in [Xamarin.Forms.Image](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Image/). As I'm trying to create a byte[] of image manualy in Xamarin.Forms without it beening platform specific.

```
Image img = new Image();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
img.Source = ImageSource.FromSource(()=>ms);
```

data is the byte[] created pixel by pixel, but how many bytes are one pixel here? Because img isn't created as it has height and width of -1. Thanks

Comment: ImageSource is a standard bitmap supported by the underlying platform - typically jpg or png, but others may work.

Comment: So the color depth is 32 bits per pixel?